# Gridstack.js get positions from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working now with [Gridstack.js](https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js) and it's good for me, but (there is always a but) does someone knows how i can position the grid-stack-item as defined in a JSON array?

**Example HTML**

```
<div class="grid-stack">
    <div id="1" class="grid-stack-item">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="2" class="grid-stack-item">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="3" class="grid-stack-item">
            <div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My JSON**

```
 [{"widgetId":"1","x":0,"y":2,"width":3,"height":4},{"widgetId":"2","x":1,"y":6,"width":3,"height":1},{"widgetId":"3","x":0,"y":7,"width":3,"height":4}]
```

I can not find anything about that in the documentation. And i am afraid i is not possible.

Comment: Uhh ok, maybe i can use the "add_widget(el, x, y, width, height, auto_position)" to do that? Just looping through the JSON with a function? Or isn't that the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a terrible headache figuring out how to make this possible. I get my grid data from a jQuery post which returns JSON data and builds te positions array. In your case this could be:

```
    var seri_data = [];
    this.serialized_data = seri_data;

    jQuery.post( 'yourfile.php', function( data ) {
            
        jQuery.each( data, function( key, value ) {

            seri_data.push({
                'id'        : this.widgetId,
                 'x'        : this.x,
                 'y'        : this.y,
                 'width'    : this.width,
                 'height'   : this.height,
             });
            
         });
            
     });
```

Use the code below, it's the base of the gridstack serialization demo example which can be found [here](https://gridstackjs.com/demo/serialization.html). Open that page's source and look at the load function part... Change it's code with the code provided below.

```
 _.each( items, function( node ) { this.grid.add_widget( jQuery( '<div data-gs-id="widget_' + node.id + '" class="grid-stack-item"><div class="grid-stack-item-content"></div></div>' ), node.x, node.y, node.width, node.height ); }, this );
```