# How to build grid from Gridstack with saved html

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I've been using Gridstack for dynamically creating a grid. I have used the following function to serialize the grid and it's data. But I can't seem to figure out how to build my grid **and** its content from the JSON array it created. Ive checked https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#load-grid-from-array, but adding the content part is the whole problem.

```
function saveData() {
        var s_data = [];

        $('.grid-stack-item.ui-draggable').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            s_data.push({
                x: $this.attr('data-gs-x'),
                y: $this.attr('data-gs-y'),
                w: $this.attr('data-gs-width'),
                h: $this.attr('data-gs-height'),
                content: $('.grid-stack-item-content', $this).html()
            });
        });         
    }
```

And that creates the following array:

```
[
    {"x":"0","y":"0","w":"4","h":"2","content":"<h1>Test title for content</h1>"},
    {"x":"4","y":"0","w":"4","h":"4","content":""}
];
```

So my question is: how can I build my grid, including its content, using this array?

Comment: Just had to add node.content on the right place. Solved!

Comment: @ can you please elaborate your solution?

Answer (score 6):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983071/gridstack-js-get-positions-from-json).

In your case, you can use the following code in the load function provided by the gridstack serialization example:

```
this.load_grid = function () {              

    var items = GridStackUI.Utils.sort( this.s_data );
    this.grid.remove_all();

    _.each( items, function( node ) {
        this.grid.add_widget( jQuery( '<div class="grid-stack-item"><div class="grid-stack-item-content">' + node.content + '</div></div>' ), node.x, node.y, node.width, node.height );
    }, this );

}.bind( this );
```